# How to solve the problem of environmental failure under distributed training

Tags: python, ssh

I am currently using a script for distributed training. The training logic is that the script can log in to another server without a password and make the same python call. I use conda for environment maintenance on each host.

Now, it seems that if I directly use a command like `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 43.0.0.1 'cd /sgnn/dist; conda activate sgnn;(export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2; python3 distDemo.py)'`, an error message similar to the following will be reported:

```
bash: conda: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distDemo.py", line 8, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

But if I artificially separate login and command invocation, it seems that there will be no problem. I want to know how I can solve this problem.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 43.0.0.1
cd /sgnn/dist; conda activate sgnn;(export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2; python3 distDemo.py)  # right run
```

Comment: As an aside, the parentheses to run `export` and `python3` in a subshell seem entirely superfluous. In fact, you probably want simply `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 python3 distDemo.py` without a semicolon after the assngnment. (`var=value command` sets `var` to value for the duration of `command` and makes it visible to the command.)

Answer (score 0):

When logging through ssh, your profile scripts are executed; they aren't when you run a script directly via the ssh command.

So you have two ways :

### Use the full command name.

Once connected to your server, run a `which conda` (or a `type conda`, if it's an alias) to know where it is.

Then, in your command, use it instead of `conda`.

For example, if `conda` is `/usr/bin/conda`:

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 43.0.0.1 'cd /sgnn/dist; /usr/bin/conda activate sgnn;(export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2; python3 distDemo.py)'`

### Source your profile scripts in the ssh connection

We used to send ssh commands via something like (from my memory) :

`ssh user@server bash -c "test; source ~/.bash_profile; my command"`

If you wonder what `test` is, it's a dummy command that is taken as the name of the executable ($0), if I fully understood what I read once ;)

Sorry for this incomplete response, it was in another professionnal life ;). Hope you'll be able to use that as a starting point for your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, when using the full path to conda, a 'conda init' error occurs. This seems to be due to incomplete execution of conda initialization. In the end, I managed to run the program by using the full path to 'python3' within the conda environment, and this seems to work. Once again, thank you very much for your assistance.